# I'm using Powershell.When I input my code,which is $var = Read-Host ("enter a number")

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell ISE.I'm having trouble with my If statement.

When I enter in my code

```
$var = Read-Host ("enter a number")

If ($var = 1) {

    "var = 1"
}

If ($var = 1) {

    "var = 2"
}
```

I get a output of...

```
var = 1
var = 2
```

Can someone please help Me.

Comment: `=` is assignment, but not comparison.

Comment: Use == for comparison.

Comment: @WalterMitty PoweShell uses `-eq` instead of `==`

Comment: thanks.I'll try that.

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: You have two if statements _incorrectly_ evaluating the same staement `$var -eq 1` but have different output string for those. _  
It did not work._ is not useful. What did happen? What did you expect? Does your second if need to read  `If ($var -eq 2) { "var = 2"}`

Comment: Oops, my bad.  Still not thinking in posh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are expecting a result of `"var = 2"` if the user inputs `2`, and a result of `"var = 1"` if the user inputs `1`.

If so you are looking for the code:

```
$var = Read-Host ("enter a number")

If ($var -eq 1) {
    "var = 1"
}

If ($var -eq 2) {
    "var = 2"
}
```

You could also use a switch to get an equivalent outcome:

```
$var = Read-Host ("Enter a number")

switch($var){
    1 {"var = 1"}
    2 {"var = 2"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$var = Read-Host ("enter a number")

If ($var -eq 1) {

    "var = 1"
}

If ($var -eq 2) {

    "var = 2"
}
```

Comment: because you test twice -eq 1